# running mnesia node with its business logic as an OS deamon

Tags: erlang, daemon, rpc, erlang-otp, mnesia

I have developed an application which i have been running in the erlang shell by following this order.

```
$erl -name nodename@192.168.0.1 -mnesia dir '"/home/app/logic/database"' -setcookie  cookie

nodename@192.168.0.1> cd("/home/app/logic"). 

nodename@192.168.0.1> c(module1).

nodename@192.168.0.1> c(module2).

nodename@192.168.0.1> c(module3).

nodename@192.168.0.1> application:start(mnesia).

nodename@192.168.0.1>
```

Now my problem is that i want to run this application a daemon such that when i exit the **erlang** shell it continues running and communication with other nodes through **rpc:call/4.**

Comment: Please describe what approaches you've tried so far.  Do you not know where to start at all in daemonizing this application?

Comment: I have no idea on about where to start from... the issue raised as I am supposed to run the application from a virtual server where the erlang shell approach is not persistent. A full comprehensive solution is welcomed. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly look at the erl command options, you should see something like -detached which would help you doing this. http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html

Comment: Now the other issue is that you stop the node by calling application:stop(mnesia). followed by q(). How can i do the same for the deamon

Comment: You have to call it from another node using rpc.

Comment: `escript` also helps to connect to detached nodes via a scripting interface. Windows erlang services can be created using: `erlsrv`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly well.

```
$erl -name nodename@192.168.0.1 -pa /home/app/logic -mnesia dir '"/home/app/logic/database"' -eval "application:start(mnesia)" -setcookie cookie -detached
```

Now I am thinking whether this works to stop mnesia safely

```
$erl -name nodename@192.168.0.1 -pa /home/app/logic -mnesia dir '"/home/app/logic/database"' -eval "application:stop(mnesia)" -setcookie cookie -detached
```

Comment: Managing mnesia running started as above is better to get a peer erlang node i.e a node having the same cookie

Answer (score 0):

Managing a node mnesia running as a daemon is easier to use a peer erlang node i.e a node having the same cookie i.e

```
$erl -name node_name@domain_name -setcookie cookie
```

Then send all commands to the mnesia node by rpc:call/4 for example to stop mnesia safely use this

```
node_name@domain_name> rpc:call("nodename@192.168.0.1",application,stop,[mnesia]).
```

Actually this works for all erlang nodes running as daemon whether running mnesia application of any application.